# Flash ExternalInterface sniffer

Tags: javascript, flash, externalinterface

I want to see all the calls that a Flash object is making to the Javascript on my browser. 
Is there an ExternalInterface sniffer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be able to do this with [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/), not 100% sure though.  You could also use the script panel in Firebug, maybe?

Don't mean to be vague, I just don't have the ability to verify my suggestions right now :)

Comment: no,http proxy like "Charles" won’t help also firebug is no good here
i need to monitor the communication between the browser DOM and the flash component.